# How to get document by ID using mongoose with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get a single document by ID from a $http request using mongoose and Angularjs (learning Angular CLI). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can get the id but cannot figure out how to pass it to the routing

Controller for Single Article View:

```
let _id = $routeParams;


console.log(_id);

$http({
    cache: true,
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/article/:id',
    params: { _id }
}).then(function successCallback(res) {
    $scope.article = res.data;
}).catch(function errorCallback(err) {
    if (err) {
        alert('THERE WAS AN ERROR');
    }
})
```

Html:

```
        <a id="modalButton" ng-href="/articles/{{article._id}}">READ MORE...</a>
```

Mongoose Routing:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next){
Article.findById(req.params.id, function(err, article){
        if(err) {
        return err;
     } else {
        res.json(article);
        console.log(article);
   } 
});
});
```

Article Scheme:

```
var ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
image: String,
title: String,
about: String,
article: String,
_id: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

I would really appreciate any help. This has been giving me trouble for a week now.

Comment: *using mongoose with Angularjs*: are you building a client that sends requests directly to a MongoDB?

Comment: `/:id`  should be `/articles/:id`

Comment: Yes to get a single document that is then sent to a single article page. So it is a list of all my documents then when 'Read More' is clicked the page makes a 'get' call to mongo for that document ID

Comment: let me try that

Comment: /articles/:id did not work. This is really giving me trouble. Thank you for helping Sravan and RaphaMex

Comment: what is _Mongoose Routing:_ ? this is express routing probably